# Group GPS coordinates to create Clusters/ CLLI codes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, gps

Hi I have a list of addresses with GPS co-ordinates that I need to cluster into groups of around 600 addresses to create Grouping id's. The groupings should be almost square polys.

These are the specifications of what I have:

Program: Oracle

Records: 522,000

My data has the following Columns:

```
GEO_ID (Primary Key)
MUN_NAME (VarChar)(City Name)
LONUM (Int)(House number)
DISTANCE (int)
FCODE (int)
FCODE_DES (VarChar)(Dwelling Type)
LATITUDE (Int)
LFNAME (Street string)
LONGITUDE (Int)
OBJECTID (Int)
WARD_NAME (VarChar)
X (Int)
Y (Int)
```

Based on my calculations on our system limitations the required group fields below states how many clusters would need to be created to not exceed the 600 cluster limitation from our system.

```
 City              addresses  Max Clusters  Required Clusters
 York               32277        600        53
 East York          23957        600        39
 Former Toronto     156563       600        260
 Etobicoke          72721        600        121
 North York         113542       600        189
 Scrborough         123016       600        205
```

Ideally i would like to do all of this in oracle and be able to run this query to create new groupings or add addresses to existing grouping should they appear in the data.

I am totally lost on how to do this, i read through a couple posts on K means but could not figure out how to create the groupings.

This is the code that i have so far:

`Select LONGITUDE,
LATITUDE,
lat_diff, 
long_diff,
(power(lat_diff,2)+power(long_diff,2))
From
(
Select 
LONGITUDE,
LATITUDE,
COALESCE( Latitude - lag(Latitude, 1 , Null) over (order by Latitude), Latitude)as lat_diff,
Round(COALESCE( Longitude - lag(LONGITUDE, 1 , Null) over (order by LONGITUDE), LONGITUDE),20) as long_diff,
Latitude || '-' ||
Lead( Latitude, 1,0) over (order by Latitude) as prev_Latitude
From RPT.GTA_ADDRESS_DATA
ORDER BY LATITUDE asc
)`

Thanks !

Comment: can you explain a litle more what you want to do with that data? And yes there are K-mean algorithms to do that, but those will make group so average distance between address is similar. Not sure if that will full fill your requirement of square polygons.

Comment: btw, we can help if you found some error while trying to wrote the code. We **WONT** write the code for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt response i was following this tutorial 
http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/ on how to create the k means in sql but i can't figure out how i am supposed to group the data from where i am now in my query.

Comment: Are LATITUDE and LONGITUDE columns really `integer`? This would be a resolution of app. 111km

Comment: My apologies they are actually set as number. So how would i modify this code to give me a distance ?

Comment: Can anyone please provide some guidance ? not sure where to go from here